# Python - Using min() to find min value in JSON object?

Tags: python, json, geojson, min

So I have a geojson object that has:

```
"features" : [{"properties": {"rank": 10}},{"properties": {"rank": 2}}]
```

and so on. I want to find the minimum rank and use the [min](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#min) method. So I tried something like this:

```
features = geojson["features"]
min(features["properties"]["rank"])
```

and then:

```
features = geojosn["features"]["properties"]["rank"]
min(features)
```

and got this on both:

> TypeError: List indices must be integers of slices, not str

What am I doing wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm assuming you have a list of features with properties (as @idjaw pointed out your data structure is invalid). Then `geojson['features']` is a list and you aren't indexing the list. You can do this with a generator:

```
min(feature["properties"]["rank"] for feature in geojson['features'])
```

Alternatively if you want the whole feature back then you can use key:

```
min(geojson['features'], key=lambda feature: feature["properties"]["rank"])
```

Comment: But basically, `feature` acts as the list iterator here to loop through the elements of features?

Comment: Thanks for the answer!! :)